# how to covert arabic text in json_decode

Tags: php, utf-8, json, arabic

```
 $response="بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم";       
 $string='{

    "something": "'.$response.'"
}';
```

Please give me a solution to json_decode above string. 
When I try json_decode($string, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
result is  null

Comment: What kind of JSON wrapper API around PDO is that? Just seems to be substituting SQL injection for JSON injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably  json_decode have problem with arabic charactor.
The arabic text should convert to utf-8.if after decode also the arabic text coming properly hope you will get the result.

```
@header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


$response="بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم";  

$response= iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', ($response)); 
$string='{

"something": "'.$response.'"
}';

echo "Before Decode :";
var_dump($string);

echo "After Decode :";
$json=json_decode($string);
var_dump($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the `charset` of your `DBMS` to one that suits your needs.

Assuming your are using `MySQL` and `PHPMyAdmin`, you have to go to your `PHPMyAdmin` page and choose an appropriate charset. The default is, as far as I remember, `UTF-8`.

Comment: Where did you get the idea the OP is using PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @deceze true :) I will never install anything which starts with `PHP` on my server. And mysql cli is perfectly fine.